# Drupal Search- Linking Multiple Entities with Relations as a Single Unit

Tags: search

I've got a site that currently uses Views exposed filters for search.  I'm looking at other search solutions for Drupal in an attempt to make more complicated searches possible.

The searches on my site are of users, but the catch is that each user, in addition to a user profile, has four nodes of four different content types connected to that profile with relations (from the Relation module).  These four nodes should also be considered part of the user profile.

In Views, I handle this by adding the four relations to the view, which allows me to pull the four pieces of content into the view.  My question is, is there a way to use Search API (with or without Solr) to link each user profile with its content based on the relations?  Or is there another search solution for Drupal that can accomplish this?

I don't need a step-by-step tutorial; I just want to understand whether it's possible to use relations from the Relation module to link entities (nodes and users) as a single "unit" in search in Drupal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turns out to be really easy.  On the **Create Index** page, just add the **Related Entity (User->Node)** Option for the relevant relation.  The entities will then all be index together as a single unit and you can do Views and Facets and all sorts of fun things with them.